# Templated conversion operator prevents operator usage of (implicit) converted-to type

Tags: c++, templates, operators, implicit-conversion

I am trying to understand why the compiler is able to use the operator `int operator+(const int lhs, const int rhs)` with the regular conversion function in the `Wrapper` class, but as soon as I make it templated, it fails compilation (no  `operator+` available for `Wrapper<int> + Wrapper<int>`)

```
template<typename Type_T>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    template<typename Type_U = Type_T> //-> this triggers compilation failure
    operator Type_T() const
    {
        return m_object;
    }

    Type_T m_object;
};

int main()
{    
    Wrapper<int> a;
    Wrapper<int> b;

    int result = a + b;

    return 0;
}
```

I realise that the conversion declaration as a template is redundant since I'm not actually doing anything with the template argument, but that has me all the more puzzled as to why the compilation result is different
(My actual use case was to do with `std::enable_if_t`(restricted to C++17) and changing conversion behaviour based on the wrapped type, but it turned out to be just the templated conversion operator causing the issue)

Note that it *does* work if I am explicit about the conversions like this:
`int result = (int)a + (int)b;`

I am guessing this is to do with the implicit conversion limit, but am not sure why the addition of the template argument changes how the addition is interpreted
Could anyone please clarify this to me and/or point me to the C++ specification that is responsible for this behaviour?

Godbolt example code: https://godbolt.org/z/G4Taqvz4r

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Is the "uncommented version" `operator Type_T` or `operator Type_U` ?

Comment: The template operator creates an infinite number of possible conversion paths, with no way to choose between them.  The default type parameter doesn't matter, because it's a context that would be inferred.

Comment: if `operator Type_U` why default parameter? if `operator Type_T`, why template?

Comment: @BenVoigt How so? The conversion is always to `Type_T`, so in this case to `int`. The operator is not `operator Type_U()`, it's still `operator Type_T()` (check the godbolt link).

Comment: @Nelfeal - But there is still an infinite number of operators, even if they all return `int`. The compiler cannot just choose one at random.

Comment: To clarify, the original usage was:
`template<typename Type_U = Type_T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<Type_U>, int>`

Where std enable if requires the template argument to be part of the template declaration, and can't directly use Type_T

Comment: I also fail to see how this triggers an infinite number of possible operators, the default template argument is `Type_T` (aka int), should it not simple be turning into a conversion call under the template declaration for int? ie `Wrapper<int>::int<int>() const` (or whatever a conversion function call syntax looks like :P)

Comment: @AG_Alex2097 What Ben Voigt meant and BoP clarified is that because this is in the context of a conversion, the operator could be instantiated with any type for `Type_U`. The default argument doesn't matter, and the fact that all the possible instantiations convert to `int` doesn't matter either. The compiler cannot pick one in particular.

Comment: @Nelfeal: The godbolt link compiled.  It was not clear from the question whether the alternate version, with the template uncommented, should be `operator Type_T` or `operator Type_U`.  To be clear about that there should be two entirely separate definitions, using something like `#if`/`#else` to enable one at a time.

Comment: @Nelfeal I see, thank you for clarifying, I wasn't aware conversions were treated differently on this matter

Comment: @BenVoigt sorry it wasn't immediately obvious, I've updated the godbolt link to reflect your suggestion of using a #if #else

And thank you all for your replies! :)

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, OP did write "I'm not actually doing anything with the template argument". I agree it can still be ambiguous because having `operator Type_U` would be typical, but neither option compiled anyway. I was initially confused because I didn't think you could have multiple instantiations with the exact same signatures. But I guess there is nothing in the standard that prevents it.